# Python text mining

Tags: python

I have a function get_numbers('X') that runs a Bing search to find a contact number for 'X', i.e. get_numbers('Google') would return a customer service contact number. I want to extend the search by running Bing search on different forms of the company name. And then run a for loop to run get_numbers on all the versions of the name.

```
def company_names(company):
    etc =['','ltd','plc', 'inc']
    names = [ '{} {}'.format(company,i) for i in etc ]
    return names

def get_more_numbers(company):

    company = company_names(company)
    for i in company:
        name = company[i]
        get_numbers(name)
```

I'm getting the error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-22-716ce1744cc0>", line 5, in get_more_numbers
    name = company[i]

TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: It looks as if you think "i" is an integer, it's actually the value of each of the elements in the array of company, not an index into the array.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have string as indices. You are iterating using a for each of string. `i` will contain the name. Not the index.
You can remove this line.

```
name = company[i]
```

And replace next line with `get_numbers(i)`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
for i in company:
    name = company[i]
    get_numbers(name)
```

by:

```
for name in company:
    get_numbers(name)
```